# Why jest doesn't call a function that is inside the useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have an async function `setInitialData` that is called in `useEffect` hook in the apps `provider`. I want to test that the function has been called. This test is failing. Why?

```
const dispatch = jest.fn();
const state = {...}
jest.mock('../context/actions', () => ({
  setInitialData: jest.fn(),
}));

test('setInitialData fn is called in useEffect hook in the provider', () => {
  const {debug} = render(<CurrencyExchange />, {state, dispatch});
  expect(setInitialData).toHaveBeenCalled();
});


Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Just to give a bit more context I have a custom `render` function so my component is in the provider:

```
const customRender = (ui, {state = {}, dispatch = () => undefined, ...options} = {}) => {
  function Wrapper({children, props}) {
    return (
      <CurrencyStateContext.Provider value={state} {...props}>
        <CurrencyDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CSSReset />
            {children}
          </ThemeProvider>
        </CurrencyDispatchContext.Provider>
      </CurrencyStateContext.Provider>
    );
  }
  return render(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...options});
};
export {customRender as render};
```

And the actual Provider implementation looks like this:

```
function CurrencyProvider({children}: CurrencyProviderProps): JSX.Element {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<React.Reducer<CurrencyState, Action>>(reducer, initialState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInitialData(dispatch);
  }, []);
```

--- **EDIT** ---

Ok. I have. moved

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInitialData(dispatch);
  }, []);
```

In to `CurrencyExchange` component and now I get expected assertions. 
But still, can anyone explain to me why the `setInitialData` is not called when it's located directly in apps provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` is asynchronous so you have to wait for it using [`act`](https://github.com/aneurysmjs/react-shop/blob/3d9fcba4b02f17e5b8c28b5fa3c6f6771007ded1/src/app/components/shared/LazyComponent/LazyComponent.test.js). `useLayoutEffect` is synchronous

to wait for `useEffect` you can try this

```js
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils'

test('setInitialData fn is called in useEffect hook in the provider', () => {
  let debug
  await act(async () => { 
    debug = render(<CurrencyExchange />, {state, dispatch}).debug;
  })

  expect(setInitialData).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```